# Many To Many Mapping Issue

Tags: php, doctrine, annotations

I'm currently trying to map music related data using Doctrine2's POPO Annotations.

I haven't had problems mapping any other many-to-many relations, but one specific relation is giving me trouble. It does not throw an error, but the mapping does not get inserted into the mapping table (`artist_album`)

**Artist**:

```
<?php
/**
 * @orm:Entity
 * @orm:Table(name="artist")
 */
class Artist
{

    ...

     /**
     * @orm:ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company\MusicBundle\Entity\Album", inversedBy="artists", cascade={"persist"})
     * @orm:JoinTable(name="artist_album",
     *      joinColumns={@orm:JoinColumn(name="artist_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@orm:JoinColumn(name="album_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     *      
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    private $albums;

    ...

}
```

**Album**

```
    ....

    /**
     * @orm:ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company\MusicBundle\Entity\Artist", mappedBy="albums", cascade={"persist"})
     * 
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    private $artists;

    ...

}
```

I'm sure it's just something in I've done wrong in the mapping, but I just can't put my proverbial finger on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was setting the artist on the inverse side of the relationship. It appears you must set the relationship on the owning side (in this case, Artist).